# insert multiple records in one field

Tags: vb.net, ms-access, insert-into

I have a code that writes in accdb file and works fine. My manager request me that the field DIAS (you will find that field below in the code) that allows multiple selection, insert all the selected values in the database. Right now it only insert the first one:

```
Imports System.Data.OleDb
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Collections.Generic
Imports System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListItem

Partial Class _Default
Inherits System.Web.UI.Page



Protected Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    Dim myConn As OleDbConnection
    Dim cmd As OleDbCommand
    Dim sqlString, FName, LName, Account, Supervisor, Type, Justification, Days, Clock, Emp, Mess As String


    FName = Name.Text
    LName = Last.Text
    Account = DropDownList1.SelectedValue
    Supervisor = DropDownList2.SelectedValue
    Type = DropDownList4.SelectedValue
    Justification = Jus.Text
    Clock = DropDownList3.SelectedValue
    Days = DropDownList6.SelectedValue
    Emp = DropDownList5.SelectedValue
    Mess = ListBox1.SelectedValue


    Response.Write("<script language=""javascript"">alert('¡Gracias por la información! Saludos!!');</script>")

    myConn = New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=F:\WFM\Database4.accdb")

    myConn.Open()
    ' sqlString = "INSERT INTO Absence (FName, LName, Account, Supervisor, Tipo, Justification, Clock, Cuando) VALUES ( " + FName + "," + LName + "," + Account + "," + Supervisor + "," + Type + "," + Justification + "," + Clock + "," + Days + ")"

    sqlString = "INSERT INTO Absence (FName, LName, Account, Supervisor, Tipo, Justification, Clock, Diass, Mess, Emp) VALUES ( @FName, @LName, @Account, @Supervisor, @Type, @Justification, @Clock, @Days, @Mess, @Emp)"
    cmd = New OleDbCommand(sqlString, myConn)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FName", FName)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LName", LName)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Account", Account)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Supervisor", Supervisor)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Tipo", Type)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Justification", Justification)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Clock", Clock)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Days", Days)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Mess", Mess)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Emp", Emp)

    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    myConn.Close()


End Sub
```

Is this possible?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: So if I understand correctly, you want to add a new row in the database for each Selected day. In each row, all field values stay the same except for the day value?  If that's the case then there is a quick solution to code.

Comment: Hi, the dropdownlist DAYS (Days = DropDownList6.SelectedValue), allows multiple selection. I need that all the selected values inserts in the same field of the DB. IE if the users selects, 1,2,3,4... currently is only adding the first value (1).

Answer (score 0):

this will add one row for each selected item in the listbox while maintaining values for other boxes.
loop through the selected days and execute the query for each day.

```
Protected Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
Dim myConn As OleDbConnection
Dim cmd As OleDbCommand
Dim sqlString, FName, LName, Account, Supervisor, Type, Justification, Days, Clock, Emp, Mess As String


FName = Name.Text
LName = Last.Text
Account = DropDownList1.SelectedValue
Supervisor = DropDownList2.SelectedValue
Type = DropDownList4.SelectedValue
Justification = Jus.Text
Clock = DropDownList3.SelectedValue
Emp = DropDownList5.SelectedValue
Mess = ListBox1.SelectedValue


Response.Write("<script language=""javascript"">alert('¡Gracias por la información! Saludos!!');</script>")

myConn = New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=F:\WFM\Database4.accdb")

myConn.Open()
' sqlString = "INSERT INTO Absence (FName, LName, Account, Supervisor, Tipo, Justification, Clock, Cuando) VALUES ( " + FName + "," + LName + "," + Account + "," + Supervisor + "," + Type + "," + Justification + "," + Clock + "," + Days + ")"

sqlString = "INSERT INTO Absence (FName, LName, Account, Supervisor, Tipo, Justification, Clock, Diass, Mess, Emp) VALUES ( @FName, @LName, @Account, @Supervisor, @Type, @Justification, @Clock, @Days, @Mess, @Emp)"
for each s as string in DropDownList6.selectedItems
   Days = s
   cmd = New OleDbCommand(sqlString, myConn)
   cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FName", FName)
   cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LName", LName)
   cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Account", Account)
   cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Supervisor", Supervisor)
   cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Tipo", Type)
   cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Justification", Justification)
   cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Clock", Clock)
   cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Days", S)
   cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Mess", Mess)
   cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Emp", Emp)

   cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
Next
myConn.Close()
End Sub
```

EDIT: I forgot to change the variable being passed from Days to S. Then code now reflects those changes.
Also, see this thread http://www.access-programmers.co.uk/forums/showthread.php?t=233106

Comment: Dosen't worked.

Server Error in '/' Application.

An INSERT INTO query cannot contain a multi-valued field.

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException: An INSERT INTO query cannot contain a multi-valued field.

Source Error: 


Line 48:             cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Emp", Emp)
Line 49: 
Line 50:             cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
Line 51:         Next

Comment: Something wrong with this param? Line 48: cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Emp", Emp)

I'm not sure where this error is coming from. Someone on here will probably recognize it and be able to better address your question.

Comment: No, the error is when I select multiple records to write in accdb file

Exception Details: System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException: An INSERT INTO query cannot contain a multi-valued field.

If I select one record the app works fine